# Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByOption() on a non-object

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I am facing a problem. I have installed Vodes 1.5 in website. In admin panel, when I click on the save button I get the error "

> Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByOption() on a non-object in /var/www/Joomla/administrator/components/com_vodes/models/config.php on line 58 ".

This is the code we are using :

```
function save(){
    // initialize variables.
    $table          = JTable::getInstance('component');
    $params         = JRequest::getVar('params', array(), 'post', 'array');
    $row            = array();
    $row['option']  = 'com_vodes';
    $row['params']  = $params;

    // load the component data for com_ajaxregister
    if (!$table->loadByOption('com_vodes')) {
        $this->setError($table->getError());
        return false;
    }

    // bind the new values
    $table->bind($row);

    // check the row.
    if (!$table->check()) {
        $this->setError($table->getError());
        return false;
    }

    // store the row.
    if (!$table->store()) {
        $this->setError($table->getError());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Please help to sought it out.

Comment: If you have a bug with a 3rd party extension, please contact the developer. Beforehand, ensure you are running the latest version of Vodes

Comment: Lodder i have upgraded vodes from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.3.3. There is no latest version of vodes in joomla 3.3.3. So i have to upgrade it .

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look at the developer site for Vodes. The extension is only compatible with Joomla 1.0 and 1.5 with a possibility or running on Joomla 2.5, but most definitely not Joomla 3.x

There are extreme coding differences between Joomla 1.5 and 3.x therefore extensions will throw errors all over the place, or worse, not work at all.

You will have to find an alternative to Vodes or make the whole extensions Joomla 3.x compatible which I can assure you, will not be a 5 minute job